# Stopping task on AWS ECS via CLI (program output as argument input bash)

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

I'm trying to kill a task in ECS via the CLI.

I can fetch the task name by executing:

```
aws ecs list-tasks --cluster "my-cluster" --service-name "my-service" | jq .taskArns[0]
```

which outputs:

```
"arn:aws:ecs:REGION:ACCOUNT-ID:task/TASK-GUID"
```

the full ARN of the task as a string (I have a global defaulting output to JSON).

I can kill the task by executing:

```
aws ecs stop-task --cluster "my-cluster" --task "task-arn"
```

However when I try and combine it:

```
aws ecs stop-task --cluster "my-cluster" --task $(aws ecs list-tasks --cluster "my-cluster" --service-name "my-service" | jq .taskArns[0])
```

I get:

> An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the StopTask operation: taskId longer than 36.

I know this is probably bash program output/argument input interpolation but I've looked that up and cannot get to the bottom of it.

Comment: What is the output of `aws ecs list-tasks --cluster "my-cluster" --service-name "my-service" | jq .taskArns[0]`

Comment: Does the `ARN` have any special characters? Can you try the command substitution within quotes as follows:  `aws ecs stop-task --cluster "my-cluster" --task "$(aws ecs list-tasks --cluster "my-cluster" --service-name "my-service" | jq .taskArns[0])"
`

Comment: Also note that the aws cli essentially has jq built in so a better (simpler) way to query your task arn would be with: `aws ecs list-tasks --cluster "my-cluster" --service "my-service" --output text --query taskArns[0]`

Comment: @Inian alas that didn't work. Example ARN included.

Comment: @Simon What does `echo "$(aws ecs list-tasks --cluster "my-cluster" --service-name "my-service" | jq .taskArns[0])"` output?

Comment: @123 it outputs the ARN as a quoted string. Exactly as the original command outputs.

Comment: @Simon Is it possible the quotes are what are causing a problem? Does `aws ecs stop-task --cluster "my-cluster" --task '"arn:aws:ecs:REGION:ACCOUNT-ID:task/TASK-GUID"'` give the same error? Note the outside single quotes.

Comment: @Simon, instead of `$()`, can you try backticks: aws ecs stop-task --cluster "my-cluster" --task \`aws ecs list-tasks --cluster "my-cluster" --service-name "my-service" | jq .taskArns[0\]`

Comment: @helloV That would make zero difference.

Comment: @nathanpeck when executing with your solution rather than jq it works. Do you want to submit and it as an answer? I guess the piping between aws and jq within the ticks/$() doesn't work... anyone shine light on this?

Comment: @Simon Submitted as an answer. :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

AWS cli essentially has jq built in so a better (simpler) way to query your task arn would be with:

```
aws ecs list-tasks --cluster "my-cluster" --service "my-service" --output text --query taskArns[0]
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe that helps someone:

Killing task with unique task definition name:

```
OLD_TASK_ID=$(aws ecs list-tasks --cluster ${ecsClusterName} --desired-status RUNNING --family ${nameTaskDefinition} | egrep "task/" | sed -E "s/.*task\/(.*)\"/\1/")
aws ecs stop-task --cluster ${ecsClusterName} --task ${OLD_TASK_ID}
```

Killing multiple tasks (same task definition name but different task ids):

```
OLD_TASK_IDS=$(aws ecs list-tasks --cluster ${ecsClusterName} --desired-status RUNNING --family ${nameTaskDefinition} | egrep "task/" | sed -E "s/.*task\/(.*)\"/\1/" | sed -z 's/\n/ /g')
IFS=', ' read -r -a array <<< "$OLD_TASK_IDS"
for element in "${array[@]}"
do
    aws ecs stop-task --cluster ${ecsClusterName} --task ${element}
done
```

Comment: how to get this ${nameTaskDefinition} using command ?

Comment: Please check the aws ecs list-tasks docu: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/list-tasks.html

Answer (score 1):

One-liner version of nathanpecks great answer:

`aws ecs stop-task --cluster "my-cluster" --task $(aws ecs list-tasks --cluster "my-cluster" --service "my-service" --output text --query taskArns[0])`

Answer (score 0):

One-liner command to stop tasks in cluster/service

```
for taskarn in $(aws ecs list-tasks --cluster ${YOUR_CLUSTER} --service ${YOUR_SERVICE} --desired-status RUNNING --output text --query 'taskArns'); do aws ecs stop-task --cluster ${YOUR_CLUSTER} --task $taskarn; done;
```